# Where do the workflow title columns available to a list view reside?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, designer-workflow, site-column

When I create a SharePoint designer workflow it adds a column with the title of the workflow to the default view on the list that displays it's status, i.e. In Progress or Completed.

My question is, where does this information reside? The problem I have is there are 2 items with identical titles but one of them doesn't have a value. I'm not sure when this appeared, but I'd like to get rid of it becaue it causes confusion and doesn't provide any value. The only place I can see it is when I create or modify a list view or in workflows.

When I select the one that doesn't contain a value it causes me to have to go back and pick the other. Since they have identical names it's hard to tell which one I actually want.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my issue.
When I create a workflow on a list(or library) for instance "myWF", a column is added to the list called "myWF". as the workflow runs the status shows up in this column(In Progress, Completed). 
Problem is, at some point I sometimes get a second column with the same name "myWF" that doesn't show anything. It is an issue when I have some other action that needs to know when this workflow is completed, but the only way to find which column to monitor is trial and error. how can i remove the 2nd column so it doesn't confuse me?

Comment: I figured out more information. this happens when you create a list, or library from a template. the old workflows stick around as pickable columns in view even though the workflows aren't available. if you create a new workflow with the same title you have 2 columns with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a URL field that points to the workflow status page for the workflow instance on that list item. You should be able to see the column definition in List Settings.

(BTW, I have an article on setting the text value of the URL field: http://www.schaeflein.net/setting-workflow-status-in-visual-studio-and-sharepoint-designer/)